# Solving integro-differential equation with boundary condition at infinity

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, nonlinear, integral-equations, boundary-condition-at-infinity

I wish to solve a differential equation that contains a hard-to-evaluate integral and to plot the solution in a range at least $r\in(0,10)$. The equation comes from a Hartree equation (Schroedinger equation). The solution must satisfy the boundary condition $u[\infty]=1$ but I don't know how to tell *Mathematica* to consider this constraint.

```
eps = 10^-5;
end = 12;
a = -74.04252664070837;
b = 208.01432471151327;
d = -65.08706834153939;
A = 1.56692098226;
gamma = 1;

chi = 9.697836405827061;
kst=6.03474; (* actually i don't know this value exactly this is the best up to now*)
j[x_, r_] = 2 A^2 r x
g0[x_, r_] =  a + b/2 + 3 d/4 + A^2 (b + d) (x^2 + r^2) + d A^4 ((x^2 + r^2)^2 + 4 x^2 r^2)
g1[x_, r_] = j[x, r] (b + 2 d) + 4 d A^4 r x (r^2 + x^2)
f[x_] = x/Sqrt[x^2 + 2]
FNB[r_] :=  NIntegrate[(x^3/(2 + x^2) E^(-A^2 (r^2 + x^2)) (g0[x, r] BesselI[0, j[x, r]] -g1[x, r] BesselI[1, j[x, r]])), {x, 0, Infinity}] 
Plot[FNB[r], {r, 0, 5}]
eqnNB = u''[r] + u'[r]/r - u[r]/r^2 + u[r] - chi*(u[r])^(5) - 2 (Pi)^(3/2)/A u[r] FNB[r] == 0;
SolNB = NDSolve[{eqnNB, u[eps] == 0, u'[eps] == kst}, {u}, {r, eps, end}];
R[r_] = u[r] /. SolNB;
PlotNB = Plot[R[r]^2, {r, eps, end}]
FNB2[r_] :=  NIntegrate[(x R[x]^2 E^(-A^2 (r^2 + x^2)) (g0[x, r] BesselI[0, j[x, r]] - g1[x, r] BesselI[1, j[x, r]])), {x, 0, Infinity}];
eqnNB2 = u''[r] + u'[r]/r - u[r]/r^2 + u[r] - chi*(u[r])^(5) - 2 (Pi)^(3/2)/A u[r] FNB2[r] == 0;
SolNB2 = NDSolve[{eqnNB, u[eps] == 0, u'[eps] == kst}, {u}, {r, eps,end}];
R2[r_] = u[r] /. SolNB2;
PlotNB2 = Plot[R2[r]^2, {r, eps, end}]
```

I tried to compute the integral `FNB[r]` at first with a trial function `f[x]` similar to the solution I want to get, so that the value of the integral doesn't change so much. The problem is that the solution I get from the first iteration doesn't satisfy the boundary condition (this is quite obvious since I didn't tell Mathematica to satisfy it...), and also I don't get any solution from the second iteration when I try to compute the integral `FNB[r]` with the previously found solution.

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to meet your description, where's the iteration? Also, where's the definition of `rst` and `yst`?

Comment: @xzczd sorry, I've edited the code. The iteration is just another NDsolve to find the solution using the integral `FNB2[r]` computed using the solution found in the first iteraction `SolNB`

Comment: So the original `FNB` is `NIntegrate[(x u[x]^2 E^(-A^2 (r^2 + x^2)) (g0[x, r] BesselI[0, j[x, r]] - g1[x, r] BesselI[1, j[x, r]])), {x, 0, Infinity}]`, right?

Comment: Yes, but at first I used a trial function `x/Sqrt[x^2+2]` to find the solution in the first iteration for NDsolve, otherwise it told me that the equation was delayed. I think it's a good compromise.

Comment: The asymptotic limit of the equation is `u[r] - chi*u[r]^5  - (2 Pi)^(3/2)/A u[r] FNB[r] == 0`.  Hence, the asymptotic solution is approximately, `((1 - FNB[12] (2 Pi)^(3/2)/A)/chi)^.25`, which is `2.13479`, not `1` as in the  article you cited.  Until this discrepancy is resolved, there is no point to trying to solve the complete equation.

Comment: @bbgodfrey you are right about `u[r]/r^2` and `chi*(u[r])^(5)` , I've edited the post. I think the discrepancy you noticed it's because the right term is `2(Pi)^(3/2)/A u[r] FNB[r]`  and NOT `(2Pi)^(3/2)/A u[r] FNB[r]`  (the `2` is not powered by `3/2`. Thank you for pointing out this mistake

Comment: Still too large by a factor of two.  Note this this is a separatrix problem, which is very sensitive to numerical details.

Comment: @bbgodfrey I don't understand: the value of `FNB[r]` shouldn't be 0 at infinity thanks to the factor `E^(-A^2 r^2)` in the integral?

Comment: No, because the modified Bessel functions are exponentially large.  I get the same numerical result for FNB that @AlexTrounev gets.  (However, his answer for `u` is wrong, because, he uses too small a value for `kst`.  `u == 0` is an attractor, so any value of `kst` that is too small will lead to a solution oscillating about `u == 0`.  On the other hand, any value of `kst` that is too large leads to an exponentially growing  solution.  This is what makes the problem hard to solve.)

Comment: So i think the article I cited is not self-consistent: I have to find different values for the parameters `a,b,d,A `that fit the asymptotic condition you wrote, right? Only then one can solve the equation.

Comment: At the end of Sec 2 of the article, `a`, `b`, and `A` have the values you use, but `d` is `9.5`.  The resulting asymptotic value of `u` is `1.26`, closer but still not right.  I believe that the equation can be solved once the constants are determined.

Comment: @bbgodfrey At first I used the value of `d` the Author gives in the plot's caption on page 5615, that says `d=1` when `\[Gamma]=1` (that makes the exponential of `u` `5`). Actually in my own paper I have different values of `A,a,b,d` so now I tried with them, choosing the value of `chi` that satisfies your asymptotic condition. Should I edit the post with the new parameters? I'm now seeing the thing you said before: for properly high values of `kst` the solution seems to approach 1 and not be attracted from `0`

Comment: @bbgodfrey I've edited the post.

Comment: Now my best value for kst is `kst=6.034742740284` manages to give a nice solution up to `r=6`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An iterative solution to the integro-differential equation, as requested by the OP, appears reasonable.  Begin with

```
Off[InterpolatingFunction::dmval]
eps = 10^-5;
end = 12;
a = Rationalize[-74.04252664070837, 0];
b = Rationalize[ 208.01432471151327, 0];
d = Rationalize[-65.08706834153939, 0];
A = Rationalize[1.56692098226, 0];

chi = Rationalize[ 9.697836405827061, 0];
j[x_, r_] = 2 A^2 r x;
g0[x_, r_] = a + b/2 + 3 d/4 + A^2 (b + d) (x^2 + r^2) + 
    d A^4 ((x^2 + r^2)^2 + 4 x^2 r^2);
g1[x_, r_] = j[x, r] (b + 2 d) + 4 d A^4 r x (r^2 + x^2);
```

The first approximation to the integral is computed as

```
f[x_] = x/Sqrt[x^2 + 1/2];
FNB = Interpolation@Rationalize[Table[{r, E^(-A^2 (r^2 )) 
    NIntegrate[(x f[x]^2 E^(-A^2 ( x^2)) (g0[x, r] BesselI[0, j[x, r]] - 
    g1[x, r] BesselI[1, j[x, r]])), {x, 0, 30}]}, {r, 0, end, .1}], 0];
```

Note that all numerical quantities are rationalized, because subsequent `NDSolve` computations require high `WorkingPrecision`.  (High `WorkingPrecison` is necessary, because this is a separatrix computation, which is extremely sensitive to initial conditions.)  Note also that the initial guess for `u[r]`, namely `f[x_] = x/Sqrt[x^2 + 1/2]`, differs slightly from the initial guess in the question, because I felt that it would be a better first approximation, and it appears to be.  Now, solve the resulting ODE for the next approximation to `u[r]`, following the procedure described [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/173623/1063).

```
eqnNB = u''[r] + u'[r]/r - u[r]/r^2 + u[r] - chi*(u[r])^(5) - 
    2 (Pi)^(3/2)/A u[r] FNB[r] == 0;
sp = ParametricNDSolveValue[{eqnNB, u[eps] == 0, u'[eps] == up0, 
    WhenEvent[u[r] > 12/10, {bool = 1, "StopIntegration"}], 
    WhenEvent[{u[r] < 8/10, u[r] < 0}, {bool = 0, "StopIntegration"}]}, 
    u, {r, eps, end + 1}, {up0, wp0}, WorkingPrecision -> wp0, 
    Method -> "StiffnessSwitching", 
    Method -> {"ParametricSensitivity" -> None}, MaxSteps -> 100000];
bl = 1; bu = 10; imax = 200; wp = 75;
Row[{ProgressIndicator[Dynamic[ip], {0, imax}], "   ", 
    ProgressIndicator[Dynamic[rm], {0, end}]}]
Do[bool = -1; bmiddle = (bl + bu)/2; s = sp[bmiddle, wp]; 
    rm = s["Domain"][[1, 2]]; If[bool == 0, bl = bmiddle, bu = bmiddle];
    ip = i; If[bool == -1, Return[]], {i, imax}] // AbsoluteTiming
N[bmiddle, wp]
Plot[{s[r], f[r]}, {r, eps, Min[rm, end]}, PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {r, u}, 
    ImageSize -> Large, LabelStyle -> {Black, Bold, Medium}]
```

[image]

The original guess, `f[r]` agrees well with the new approximation, `s[r]`, for `r > 3`.  Now, substitute `s` into the integral.

```
FNB1 = Interpolation@Rationalize[Table[{r, E^(-A^2 (r^2 )) 
    NIntegrate[(x Piecewise[{{s[x], eps < x < end}}, f[x]]^2 E^(-A^2 ( x^2)) 
    (g0[x, r] BesselI[0, j[x, r]] - g1[x, r] BesselI[1, j[x, r]])), 
    {x, 0, 30}]}, {r, 0, end, .1}], 0];
```

and employ `NDSolve` as before to obtain the next approximation.

```
eqnNB1 = u''[r] + u'[r]/r - u[r]/r^2 + u[r] - chi*(u[r])^(5) - 
    2 (Pi)^(3/2)/A u[r] FNB1[r] == 0;
sp = ParametricNDSolveValue[{eqnNB1, u[eps] == 0, u'[eps] == up0, 
    WhenEvent[u[r] > 12/10, {bool = 1, "StopIntegration"}], 
    WhenEvent[{u[r] < 8/10, u[r] < 0}, {bool = 0, "StopIntegration"}]}, 
    u, {r, eps, end + 1}, {up0, wp0}, WorkingPrecision -> wp0, 
    Method -> "StiffnessSwitching", 
    Method -> {"ParametricSensitivity" -> None}, MaxSteps -> 100000];
bl = 1; bu = 10; imax = 200; wp = 75;
Row[{ProgressIndicator[Dynamic[ip], {0, imax}], "   ", 
    ProgressIndicator[Dynamic[rm], {0, end}]}]
Do[bool = -1; bmiddle = (bl + bu)/2; s1 = sp[bmiddle, wp]; 
    rm = s1["Domain"][[1, 2]]; If[bool == 0, bl = bmiddle, bu = bmiddle];
    ip = i; If[bool == -1, Return[]], {i, imax}] // AbsoluteTiming
N[bmiddle, wp]
Plot[{s1[r], s[r], f[r]}, {r, eps, Min[rm, end]}, PlotRange -> All, 
AxesLabel -> {r, u}, ImageSize -> Large, LabelStyle -> {Black, Bold, Medium}]
```

[image]

This process can be iterated to obtain progressively more accurate approximations.  Each iteration took about `15 minutes` on my PC.

**Addendum: Converged Iterative Solution**

Good convergence can be achieved with the following code (with constants defined above).

```
s[0][x_] = x/Sqrt[x^2 + 1/4];
FNB[0] = Interpolation@Rationalize[Table[{r, 
    E^(-A^2 (r^2 )) NIntegrate[(x s[0][x]^2 E^(-A^2 x^2) 
    (g0[x, r] BesselI[0, j[x, r]] - g1[x, r] BesselI[1, j[x, r]])), 
    {x, 0, 20}]}, {r, 0, end, .1}], 0];

mmin = 1; mmax = 20; imax = 200; wp = 75;
Row[{Dynamic[m], "   ", ProgressIndicator[Dynamic[ip], {0, imax}], 
    "   ", ProgressIndicator[Dynamic[rm], {0, end}]}]
Do[eqnNB = u''[r] + u'[r]/r - u[r]/r^2 + u[r] - chi*(u[r])^(5) - 
    2 (Pi)^(3/2)/A u[r] (FNB[m - 1][r] + FNB[Max[m - 2, 0]][r])/2 == 0;
    sp = ParametricNDSolveValue[{eqnNB, u[eps] == 0, u'[eps] == up0, 
    WhenEvent[u[r] > 11/10, {bool = 1, "StopIntegration"}], 
    WhenEvent[{u[r] < 9/10, u[r] < 0}, {bool = 0, "StopIntegration"}]}, u, 
    {r, eps, end + 1}, {up0, wp0}, WorkingPrecision -> wp0, 
    Method -> "StiffnessSwitching", 
    Method -> {"ParametricSensitivity" -> None}, MaxSteps -> 100000];
bl = 1; bu = 10;
Do[bool = -1; bmiddle = (bl + bu)/2; st = sp[bmiddle, wp]; rm = st["Domain"][[1, 2]]; 
    If[bool == 0, bl = bmiddle, bu = bmiddle]; ip = i;
    If[bool == -1, Return[]], {i, imax}];
s[m] = st; N[bmiddle, wp];
FNB[m] = Interpolation@Rationalize[Table[{r, 
    E^(-A^2 (r^2 )) NIntegrate[(x Piecewise[{{s[m][x], eps < x < end}}, 
    s[0][x]]^2 E^(-A^2 ( x^2)) (g0[x, r] BesselI[0, j[x, r]] -
    g1[x, r] BesselI[1, j[x, r]])), {x, 0, 30}]}, {r, 0, end, .1}], 0];, 
{m, mmin, mmax}]
Plot[Evaluate@Table[s[m][r], {m, mmax - 5, mmax}], {r, eps, end}, 
    PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {r, u}, ImageSize -> Large, 
    LabelStyle -> {Black, Bold, Medium}]
Plot[Evaluate@Table[FNB[m][r], {m, mmax - 5, mmax}], {r, 0, end}, 
     PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {r, "FNB"}, ImageSize -> Large, 
     LabelStyle -> {Black, Bold, Medium}]
```

[image]

[image]

Convergence is very good for both the solution, `u`, and the integral, `FNB`.  (The slight irregularity in `FNB`at large `r` is due to a slight boundary condition mismatch, which I shall fix as time permits.)  The only significant difference in the revised code used here is that `(FNB[m - 1][r] + FNB[Max[m - 2, 0]][r])/2` replaces `FNB[m - 1][r]` in `eqnNB` to improve numerical stability.  Note that this computation required `6 hours` on my pc. However, `mmax` was excessively large to assure convergence, and `mmax == 14` could have been run in `4 hours`.

**Explanation of using `WhenEvent`**

Integrating an ODE long distances along a separatrix is difficult, because the numerical solution can depart rapidly from the true solution due to small errors in the initial condition.  One method of improving the accuracy of the initial conditions is to choose initial guesses (`bl` and `bu` in the answer above) that bracket the unknown true initial condition, and then systematically reducing the uncertainty in the initial guesses by doing calculations with initial conditions that bifurcate the distance between the guesses.  So, it is necessary to stop a calculation when it obviously is departing from the separatrix, and to note whether the trial calculation is departing above or below. In the answer above, the separatrix is expected to be near `1`, except at small `r`.  So, {9/10, 11/10} are expected to bracket the separatrix, and `WhenEvent` is used to stop the calculation, when the solution moves from inside to outside that range.  (Merely being outside that range does not stop the calculation, which is why I check for `u <  0` to catch cases in which the solution never reaches the desired range in the first place.)  For a solution asymptotically approaching `2`, use `{18/10, 22/10}` or something of that sort.  Setting these limits may take some experimentation.  Ideally, the range selected should bracket the desired solution with only a modest margin of error, because a large margin of error means that more computer time is required to detect when a particular computation is leaving the expected range.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I only don't really understand how to perform iterations. I simply repeated the part of your code from the definition of `sp` to the `Plot` with the substitutions `sp→sp1`,`s→s1`,`eqnNB→eqnbNB1` ,`FNB→FNB1` and `rm→rm1` but now `NDSolve` solves the eqn just up to `0.3`. What's the problem? Can you show me how you menage to perform the iterations? Simply I'm new to _Mathematica_ and I don't understand that much your code.

Comment: @AleLenoci  I have changed the initial values of `bl` and `bu` and made a few other changes to make the code more robust.

Comment: Now using your code I can't get the right solution. Moreover I still don't understand how to perform the iteration and get your final plot...Could you please post the complete working code? thanks for the efforts

Comment: Thanks for the update @bbgodfrey. This method can work also for other similas ODEs or the parameters you set are all specific for this case?

Comment: @AleLenoci  This method should work for similar ODEs.

Comment: I still can't get the second plot from your code, i don't understand what the problem is. You are plotting the second iteration? it seems that `s1` is the same as `s`...where am I wrong?

Comment: Typo corrected.

Comment: I would like to ask you something showing you the plot I've done iterating up to 5 times your code. How can I post images in comments? Or should I edit the question/your answer? Just to show the plot for further iterations

Comment: Temporarily use the Answer box at the bottom of this page to download the picture.  Then, cut the link, place it in your comment, and delete the answer you started without posting it.  Is the solution I started not converging?

Comment: 1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KH7Kg.jpg. I see two families of solutions: one for even iterations and one for odd iterations. As the number of iterations increases it seems the solution's grows

Comment: In another notebook I also I modified `chi = Rationalize[9.697836405827061, 0];` in order to adjust the asymptotic condition (I have now a constant named `JJ = Rationalize[+0.9611852103171311, 0];` instead of `1/A` multiplying the integral in the equation). Now the solution is quite similar but I had to abort evaluation near `r=12` because seems the algorithm can't accept more points. Is there a way to fix this changing the parameters you set in the algorithm? Here's the plot of the first iteration: [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mAxXj.jpg

Comment: With respect to your first recent comment, the iteration appears to be not converging.  I must give that some thought.  With respect to the second comment, increase `end + 1` in the definition of `sp`, perhaps to `end + 3/2`.

Comment: The fact is that the solution for "even" families ( that one with peak at 2) is very similar to the plot reported in the paper i cited before, so could it be the author there just truncated the iterations..

Comment: @AleLenoci  The addition I just made to my answer gives a converged solution.  The oscillations are real.  Later today, I hope to provide a slightly more rapidly converging solution.

Comment: Is the condition you impose `WhenEvent[u[r] > 11/10, {bool = 1, "StopIntegration"}], 
    WhenEvent[{u[r] < 9/10, u[r] < 0}, {bool = 0, "StopIntegration"}]}` avoiding solutions with wide oscilations (and so divergence)? Althought it is a different equation from the one on the paper and I also changed some parameters I would expect a maximum near `r=2` and little wider oscillations. However I'm mainly interested in understanding the way to solve these equations so thanks a lot for the efforts.

Comment: My response to you question was too long for a comment, so I added it to the end of my answer.  I hope it helps.  By the way, if the answer meets your needs, please accept it by clicking the grey check mark to the left of the answer.  Reading the short tutorial for this web site provides this and other useful information.

Comment: I've posted a new question <https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/179459/solving-integro-differential-equation-numerically-with-shooting-method> about the same problem with different parameters. I'm using your code silghtlymodified to solve this problem but I cannot get convergence in those cases. I would be very grateful if you cold give a look. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I shall take a look at set 2 first.

Answer (score 1):

We can not take the eps too small, because there is a stop because of the divergence of the solution. Empirically, I picked up eps = 0.005. Then there is a solution, but it is not like expected - it's a function similar to Bessel's function.

```
eps = 5*10^-3;end = 12;
a = 1.9123;
b = -28.9815;
d = 1;
A = 1.6;
gamma = 1;
chi = 3.5;
j[x_, r_] := 2 A^2 r x
g0[x_, r_] := 
 a + b/2 + 3 d/4 + A^2 (b + d) (x^2 + r^2) + 
  d A^4 ((x^2 + r^2)^2 + 4 x^2 r^2)
g1[x_, r_] := j[x, r] (b + 2 d) + 4 d A^4 r x (r^2 + x^2)
U[0][x_] := x/Sqrt[x^2 + 2]
q[x_] := U[0][x]^2
FNB2 = Interpolation[
   Table[{r, 
     NIntegrate[(q[x]*x*
        Exp[-A^2 (r^2 + x^2)] (g0[x, r] BesselI[0, j[x, r]] - 
          g1[x, r] BesselI[1, j[x, r]])), {x, 0, Infinity}]}, {r, eps,
      end, .005}]];
U[1] = NDSolveValue[{u''[r] + u'[r]/r - u[r]/r^2 + u[r] - 
     chi*(u[r])^(5) - (2 Pi)^(3/2)/A u[r]*FNB2[r] == 0, 
   u'[eps] == 1.1, u[eps] == 0}, u, {r, eps, end}]

{Plot[U[1][r], {r, eps, end}, PlotRange -> All], 
 Plot[FNB2[r], {r, eps, end}, PlotRange -> All]}
```

[image: fig1]

Comment: thanks for the effort but as you said the solution doesn't fit boundary condition at infinity which is the key problem . I know from a paper that the solution should approach to 1 to infinity by a few dumped oscillations within the interval $(0,12)$.

Comment: Can you name the article (paper) or give a link?

Comment: Sure, look here http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/ngb23/publications/nls2.pdf. It's Eq.22, look at the plot below where's plotted `u[r]^2`

Comment: There is a difference between your equation and the equation (22). I made a change to the equation in my message, but the solution to the equation did not change qualitatively.