# Solving Integro-differential equation numerically with shooting method

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, nonlinear, integral-equations, boundary-condition-at-infinity

This question is related a question I previously asked here

[Solving integro-differential equation with boundary condition at infinity](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/176883/solving-integro-differential-equation-with-boundary-condition-at-infinity?noredirect=1#comment464182_176883)

and for which a solution was found . Now I am dealing with a similar problem with different parameters and I can't get a solution although the asymptotic condition is satisfied. The differential equation contains a complicated integral and has to be solved with a shooting method since we have boundary conditions at infinity:`s[0]=0` and `s[end]=1`.
I have 2 different sets of parameters and I'm using the code provided in the topic linked above to get the solution

```
 (*Set 1*)
\[Chi] = Rationalize[3.5, 0]
A = Rationalize[1.6, 0];
a = Rationalize[1.9123, 0];
b = Rationalize[-28.9815, 0];
d = Rationalize[9.5, 0]; 
n = Rationalize[1, 0]
B = Rationalize[1, 0]


(*Set 2*)
\[Chi] = Rationalize[0.548337, 0]
A = Rationalize[1.1809307701602592, 0];
a = Rationalize[14.593441928706284, 0];
b = Rationalize[-23.834284974146534, 0];
d = Rationalize[5.677752578949083, 0];
n = 0;
(*B is useless*)

(*Set 3*)
χ = Rationalize[0.2, 0];
A = Rationalize[3.915543336008174, 0];
a = Rationalize[181.22232071532673, 0];
b = Rationalize[124.88322492316286, 0];
d = Rationalize[-105.81583286477883, 0];
n = Rationalize[0.06779142517329072, 0];
B = Rationalize[0.479615329820981, 0];
end = 20;
```

I am using a code slightly modified from the one given by @bbgodfrey in the link given above

```
 end=12;
 eps=10^-5;
 j[x_, r_] = 2 A^2 r x;
 g0[x_, r_] = a + b/2 + 3 d/4 + A^2 (b + d) (x^2 + r^2) + d A^4 ((x^2 + r^2)^2 + 4 x^2 r^2);
 g1[x_, r_] = j[x, r] (b + 2 d) + 4 d A^4 r x (r^2 + x^2);
 jb[x_, r_] = 2 B^2 r x;
 g0b[x_, r_] = n
 s[0][x_] = x/Sqrt[x^2 + 1/4];
 FNB[0] = Interpolation@Rationalize[Table[{r,2 (Pi)^(3/2)/ A E^(-A^2 (r^2)) NIntegrate[(x s[0][x]^2 E^(-A^2 x^2) (g0[x, r] BesselI[0, j[x, r]] - 
         g1[x, r] BesselI[1, j[x, r]])), {x, 0, 30}] + 2 (Pi)^(3/2)/B E^(-B^2 (r^2)) NIntegrate[(x s[0][x]^2 E^(-B^2 x^2) (g0b[x, r] BesselI[0, jb[x, r]])), {x, 0, 30}]}, {r, 0, end, .1}], 0];

mmin = 1; mmax = 15; imax = 200; wp = 75;

Row[{Dynamic[m], "   ", ProgressIndicator[Dynamic[ip], {0, imax}], "   ", ProgressIndicator[Dynamic[rm], {0, end}]}]

Do[eqnNB = u''[r] + u'[r]/r - u[r]/r^2 + u[r] - \[Chi]*u[r]^5 - 
u[r] (FNB[m - 1][r] + FNB[Max[m - 2, 0]][r])/2 == 0;
sp = ParametricNDSolveValue[{eqnNB, u[eps] == 0, u'[eps] == up0, 
WhenEvent[u[r] > 12/10, {bool = 1, "StopIntegration"}], 
WhenEvent[{u[r] < 8/10, u[r] < 0}, {bool = 0,"StopIntegration"}]}, u, {r, eps, end + 1}, {up0, wp0}, 
WorkingPrecision -> wp0, Method -> "StiffnessSwitching",Method -> {"ParametricSensitivity" -> None}, MaxSteps -> 100000];
bl = 1; bu = 10;
Do[bool = -1; bmiddle = (bl + bu)/2; st = sp[bmiddle, wp]; 
rm = st["Domain"][[1, 2]];
If[bool == 0, bl = bmiddle, bu = bmiddle]; ip = i;
If[bool == -1, Return[]], {i, imax}];
s[m] = st; N[bmiddle, wp];
FNB[m] = Interpolation@Rationalize[Table[{r,2 (Pi)^(3/2)/A E^(-A^2 (r^2))      NIntegrate[(x Piecewise[{{s[m][x], 
           eps < x < end}}, 
         s[0][x]]^2 E^(-A^2 (x^2)) (g0[x, r] BesselI[0, j[x, r]] -
          g1[x, r] BesselI[1, j[x, r]])), {x, 0, 30}] + 
   2 (Pi)^(3/2)/
     B E^(-B^2 (r^2)) NIntegrate[(x Piecewise[{{s[m][x], 
           eps < x < end}}, 
         s[0][x]]^2 E^(-B^2 x^2) (g0b[x, r] BesselI[0, 
          jb[x, r]])), {x, 0, 30}]}, {r, 0, end, .1}], 0];, {m,mmin,mmax}]

Plot[Evaluate@Table[s[m][r], {m, mmax - 5, mmax}], {r, eps, end},PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {r, u}, ImageSize -> Large, LabelStyle ->    {Black, Bold, Medium}]
Plot[Evaluate@Table[FNB[m][r], {m, mmax - 5, mmax}], {r, 0, end},PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {r, "FNB"}, ImageSize -> Large,LabelStyle -> {Black, Bold, Medium}]
Plot[Evaluate@Table[s[m][r]^2, {m, mmax - 5, mmax}], {r, 0.01, end}, PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {"r", "n(r)"}, ImageSize -> Large, 
AxesStyle -> Directive[Black, FontSize -> 17,FontFamily -> "TeX Gyre Pagella Math"], LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, FontSize -> 17, FontFamily -> "TeX Gyre Pagella Math"], ImageSize -> {Large}, PlotRange -> All]
```

For `Set 2` integration gets stuck at the first iteration, probably due to divergence, while for `Set 1` integration gets stuck at iteration `m=4` and i really don't know why: the previous iteration was going on well and fast and were appearing oscillation in the solution that I expect as in the previous case. Here's a picture of how the solution should be (solid line) [image]

Comment: Ale Lenoci you did not define functions  `g1[x, r], j[x, r], g0b[x, r], jb[x, r]`

Comment: I've edited the question adding the missing definitions

Comment: Thanks for the definitions.  What about expressions involving `B` in Set 2?

Comment: Simply if `n=0` as in `Set 2` the functions `g0b` and `jb` are zero and so is the expression involving `B` in the integral `FNB`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Set 1**

The code in the question apparently failed to converge, because `bl` was too large.  As explained in the Addendum to my answer to [176883](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/176955/1063), `bl` and `bu` must bracket the final computed value of `up0`.  As it happens, the final value of `up0` is approximately `37/100`.  Setting

```
bl = 1/5; bu = 4;
```

meets this requirement with a significant safety margin.  (Too much margin can increase runtime by several percent.)  With this change, the converged solution after twelve iterations, which requires a few hours, is

```
Plot[Evaluate@Table[s[i][r], {i, 11, 12}], {r, eps, Min[rm, end]}, PlotRange -> All, 
    AxesLabel -> {r, u}, ImageSize -> Large, LabelStyle -> {Black, Bold, Medium}]
```

[image]

Incidentally, setting `u[eps] == up0 eps` in the definition of `sp` is slightly more accurate than setting `u[eps] == 0`, because the ODE in the question reduces to the Modified Bessel's Equation of order 1 for very small `r`.  The resulting change to the plotted solution is not visible to the eye but can impact the appropriate value of `bl`.

**Set 2**

The code in the question definitely failed for Set 2 because the values of `bl` and `bu` did not bracket the final value for `up0`.  A small amount of experimentation indicates that

```
bl = 3/10; bu = 1;
```

works well, however.  Defining

```
s[0][x_] = x/Sqrt[x^2 + 1];
```

instead of the expression in the question accelerates convergence of the iterative solution.  Finally, replacing `end + 1` by `end + 2` in the definition of `sp` improves computation of the solution near `r = end`.  (Increasing the value of `end` itself also could be considered.)  With these changes, ten iterations gives the converged solution

```
Plot[Evaluate@Table[s[m][r], {m, 9, 10}], {r, eps, end}, PlotRange -> All, 
    AxesLabel -> {r, u}, ImageSize -> Large, LabelStyle -> {Black, Bold, Medium}]
```

[image]

as desired.

**Addendum**

As requested by the OP, the Set 2 results can be computed with `end = 20` in a few hours, yielding

[image]

Note that `NIntegrate` has precision issues for larger values of `x`, which can be circumvented with the options, `WorkingPrecision -> 30, PrecisionGoal -> 8`.

**Set 3**

The OP proposed an additional set of parameters in a comment below.

```
χ = Rationalize[0.2, 0];
A = Rationalize[3.915543336008174, 0];
a = Rationalize[181.22232071532673, 0];
b = Rationalize[124.88322492316286, 0];
d = Rationalize[-105.81583286477883, 0];
n = Rationalize[0.06779142517329072, 0];
B = Rationalize[0.479615329820981, 0];
end = 20;
```

It appears that the iterative solution was not converging well for `r` near `end`.  Enough minor changes were needed to resolve this difficulty that reproducing the resulting code here makes sense.  With the functions `{j, g0, g1, jb, g0b}` as defined in the question, the code is

```
eps = 10^-5; endp = end + 1;
s[0][x_] = x/Sqrt[x^2 + 1];
FNB[0] = Interpolation@Rationalize[Table[{r, 
    2 (Pi)^(3/2)/A E^(-A^2 (r^2)) NIntegrate[(x s[0][x]^2 E^(-A^2 x^2) 
      (g0[x, r] BesselI[0, j[x, r]] - g1[x, r] BesselI[1, j[x, r]])), {x, 0, 30}, 
      WorkingPrecision -> 30, PrecisionGoal -> 8] + 
     2 (Pi)^(3/2)/B E^(-B^2 (r^2)) NIntegrate[(x s[0][x]^2 E^(-B^2 x^2) 
       (g0b[x, r] BesselI[0, jb[x, r]])), {x, 0, 30}, 
      WorkingPrecision -> 30, PrecisionGoal -> 8]}, {r, 0, endp, 1/10}], 0];

mmin = 1; mmax = 10; imax = 200; wp = 60;
Row[{Dynamic[m], "   ", ProgressIndicator[Dynamic[ip], {0, imax}], 
    "   ", ProgressIndicator[Dynamic[rm], {0, end}]}]
Do[eqnNB = u''[r] + u'[r]/r - u[r]/r^2 + u[r] - χ*u[r]^5 - 
        u[r] (FNB[m - 1][r] + FNB[Max[m - 2, 0]][r])/2 == 0;
    sp = ParametricNDSolveValue[{eqnNB, u[eps] == eps up0, u'[eps] == up0, 
        WhenEvent[u[r] > s[0][end] + 1/5 (1 - r/endp) + 1/200 (r/endp), 
            {bool = 1, "StopIntegration"}], 
        WhenEvent[{u[r] < s[0][end] - 1/5 (1 - r/endp) - 1/200 (r/endp), 
            u[r] < 0}, {bool = 0, "StopIntegration"}]}, 
        u, {r, eps, endp}, {up0, wp0}, WorkingPrecision -> wp0, 
        Method -> "StiffnessSwitching", Method -> {"ParametricSensitivity" -> None}, 
        MaxSteps -> 100000];
    bl = 1/5; bu = 2;
    Do[bool = -1; bmiddle = (bl + bu)/2; st = sp[bmiddle, wp]; 
        rm = st["Domain"][[1, 2]]; 
        If[bool == 0, bl = bmiddle, bu = bmiddle]; ip = i; 
        If[bool == -1, Return[]], {i, imax}];
    s[m] = st; N[bmiddle, wp];
    FNB[m] = Interpolation@Rationalize[Table[{r, 
        2 (Pi)^(3/2)/A E^(-A^2 (r^2)) NIntegrate[(x 
            Piecewise[{{s[m][x], eps < x < end}}, s[0][x]]^2 E^(-A^2 (x^2)) 
            (g0[x, r] BesselI[0, j[x, r]] - g1[x, r] BesselI[1, j[x, r]])), 
            {x, 0, 30}, WorkingPrecision -> 30, PrecisionGoal -> 8] + 
        2 (Pi)^(3/2)/B E^(-B^2 (r^2)) NIntegrate[(x 
            Piecewise[{{s[m][x], eps < x < end}}, s[0][x]]^2 E^(-B^2 x^2) 
            (g0b[x, r] BesselI[0, jb[x, r]])), {x, 0, 30}, 
            WorkingPrecision -> 30, PrecisionGoal -> 8]}, {r, 0, endp, 1/10}], 0];,
 {m, mmin, mmax}];
```

The main changes involve the `WhenEvent` criteria for stopping integration when a numerical solution overshoots or undershoots the expected asymptotic value of `u`, the criteria now being much more restrictive at large `r`.  There are a number of lesser changes as well.  The well converged solution is

```
Plot[Evaluate@Table[s[i][r], {i, mmax - 1, mmax}], {r, eps, Min[rm, end]}, 
    PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {r, u}, ImageSize -> Large, 
    LabelStyle -> {Black, Bold, Medium}]
```

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81341/discussion-on-answer-by-bbgodfrey-solving-integro-differential-equation-numerica).