# Nonlinear system of ODEs with boundary conditions

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, warning-messages, nonlinear, boundary-condition-at-infinity

I'm trying solve this problem:

`g'(r) = a(r)g(r)/r, (1/r)a'(r) = g(r)^2-1`

which have the following boundary conditions: `a(0)=n` and `g(infinity)=1`, where `n>=1`.

I have problem with the error for `n=1`[hence, failed for the other `n` values as well.]:

> "Infinite expression 1/0.^2 encountered"

using [`DSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DSolve.html) directly.

A work colleague solved for the values `n=1,2,5,10` using the software MAPLE. But, I don't know to use MAPLE and I would like to get these results by Mathematica. Below are the plots found by MAPLE.[image]

Comment: Please include the _Mathematica_ code text in your question.

Comment: Welcome to Mma.SE. Start by **taking the [tour] now** and learning about [asking](https://wolfr.am/wb2ijD7O) and what's [on-topic](https://wolfr.am/wb2ijD7O). Always [edit] if improvable, show due diligence, give brief context, include **minimal working example of code and data you are working on in [formatted form](https://goo.gl/ELLhTX)**. By doing all this you help us to help you and likely you will inspire great answers. The site depends on participation, as you receive **give back:** vote and answer questions, keep the site useful, be kind, correct mistakes and share what you have learned

Comment: See this [previous answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/33901/8803). Compactifying in MMA is rather trivial.

Comment: I find that `DSolve` does not produce an error message but instead returns unevaluated, meaning that it cannot solve the problem..

Comment: Maple code:`sol := proc (n) options operator, arrow; dsolve([(D(g))(r) = a(r)*g(r)/r, (D(a))(r)/r = g(r)^2-1, a(1/100000) = n, g(10) = 1], numeric) end proc;plots:-display(seq({plots:-odeplot(sol(n), [r, g(r)], linestyle = n, color = ColorTools:-Color([1/n, 1/(1+n), 1/(n+4)]))}, n = 1 .. 7));plots:-display(seq({plots:-odeplot(sol(n), [r, a(r)], linestyle = n, color = ColorTools:-Color([1/n, 1/(1+n), 1/(n+4)]))}, n = 1 .. 7));`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another way:

```
eps = 10^-10; end = 10;
sol[n_] := NDSolve[
{g'[r] == a[r]*g[r]/r, a'[r]/r == g[r]^2 - 1, a[eps] == n, g[end] == 1}
,{a[r], g[r]}, {r, eps, end}, Method -> {"Shooting", 
"StartingInitialConditions" -> {a[end] == eps, g[end] == (1 - eps)}}];

Plot[Evaluate[g[r] /. sol[#] & /@ {1, 2, 5, 10}], {r, eps, end},PlotRange -> All, 
PlotLegends -> {"n=1", "n=2", "n=5", "n=10"}, PlotLabels -> "g(r)"]
Plot[Evaluate[a[r] /. sol[#] & /@ {1, 2, 5, 10}], {r, eps, end}, PlotRange -> All, 
PlotLegends -> {"n=1", "n=2", "n=5", "n=10"}, PlotLabels -> "a(r)"]
```

[image]

For larger values e.g.`end=20`:

```
eps = 10^-20; end = 20;
sol[n_] := NDSolve["Code the same",WorkingPrecision -> 25];
Plot["Code the same"] // Quiet(*Error messages form InterpolatingFunction to Quiet *)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer,  you've been a big help.

Comment: Dear @MariuszIwaniuk, I was very grateful for the help on this occasion. Now, if it is possible to help again, how could I make a projection of these solutions in the plan? That is, would it be possible to make a density plot?

Answer (score 4):

*Error in boundary condition corrected*

To solve this ODE system, begin by determining its behavior near `r == 0`.

```
Series[{g'[r] - (a[r] g[r])/r, a'[r]/r + 1 - g[r]^2}, {r, 0, 2}] // Normal;
Thread[Flatten@CoefficientList[r % /. a[0] -> n, r] == 0];
Solve[%, {a'[0], a''[0], a'''[0], a''''[0], g[0], g'[0], g''[0], g'''[0]}]

(* a'[0] -> 0, a''[0] -> -1, a'''[0] -> 0, a''''[0] -> 0,
   g[0] -> 0, g'[0] -> 0, g''[0] -> 0, g'''[0] -> 0  *)
```

In other words, `g[r]` vanishes to all orders at the origin for most values of `n`.  However, if `n` is a positive integer, the same set of commands leaves `Derivative[n][g][0]` undetermined.  So, `g[eps]` is approximately proportional to `eps^n`.  Next, solve the equations numerically by shooting, using the method previously employed [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/179505/1063) and elsewhere on this site.  (As noted in my comment above, `DSolve` returns unevaluated when applied to these equations.)  A typical calculation for `n == 5` is given by

```
eps = 10^-5; end = 20;
sp = ParametricNDSolveValue[{g'[r] == a[r] g[r]/r, a'[r]/r == g[r]^2 - 1, 
    a[eps] == n0, g[eps] == eps^n0 gp, 
    WhenEvent[g[r] > 101/100, {bool = 1, "StopIntegration"}], 
    WhenEvent[a[r] < 0, {bool = 0, "StopIntegration"}]}, 
    {a[r], g[r]}, {r, eps, end + 5}, {gp, wp0, n0}, 
    WorkingPrecision -> wp0, Method -> "StiffnessSwitching"];
bl = 0; bu = 2; imax = 100; wp = 75; n = 5;
Do[bool = -1; bmiddle = (bl + bu)/2; st = sp[bmiddle, wp, n]; 
    rm = (First[st] /. r -> "Domain")[[1, 2]]; 
    If[bool == 0, bl = bmiddle, bu = bmiddle]; ip = i; 
    If[bool == -1, Return[]], {i, imax}]; 
s[n] = st;
```

For larger values of `n`, `wp` must be increased.  For instance, with `n = 10`, `wp = 90` is required.  Results for `n = {1, 2, 5, 10}` are plotted below.

```
Plot[{s[1], s[2], s[5], s[10]}, {r, eps, 10}, PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {r, "a, g"}, 
    ImageSize -> Large, LabelStyle -> {Black, Bold, Medium}]
```

[image]

The solutions takes no more than several seconds each.

Comment: I have appreciated your answer. Thank you very much @bbgodfrey. You've already been very helpful. A friend got solve also for values `n>1`, but he used the software MAPLE. I don't know to use the MAPLE, but I'll try to use your answer like a procedure.

Comment: @AndréCavalcante  Because the ODEs are nonlinear, not all boundary conditions are consistent with them.  In this case, I believe that `A[0] == 1` is the only consistent boundary condition, unless you are willing to accept `g[r] == 0` as a solution.  Perhaps, I could get Mathematica to produce numerical solutions for other values of `n`, but they would be incorrect, I believe.

Comment: I have edited my question and added the plots obtained by MAPLE. Indeed, using its answer it was not possible to solve for values greater than `n == 1`. In addition, by behavior near `r == 0`,  I have noticed that for `n == 2`, for example, leaves `g''[0]` undetermined.

Comment: @AndréCavalcante  I just realized that I had made an error in the `g[eps]` boundary condition.  In fact, any positive integer value of `n` gives a valid solution.  Sorry.

Comment: Again, thanks for your help.